# How does CanSignInAsync(xyz) method of SignInManager work?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In ASP.NET Core Identity, how does `CanSignInAsync(xyz)` method of SignInManager work, what's it's real purpose, and what methods of the custom store provider interfaces (e.g. IUserStore) implementations does it hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [source code of `CanSignInAsync(TUser)` Method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4303bbe78650abf0bc6941d81956b02e4357feb5/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L143), we can find this method can help check if the specified user can sign in based on confirmation status, like below.

```
public virtual async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(TUser user)
{
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(0, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed email.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        return false;
    }
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user)))
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(1, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed phone number.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        return false;
    }
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount && !(await _confirmation.IsConfirmedAsync(UserManager, user)))
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(4, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed account.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```